# Web based development on ASP.Net Platform, should I use WPF or ASP.Net/C# based UI

Tags: asp.net

For Web based development on ASP.Net Platform, should I use WPF or ASP.Net/C# based UI? or is there any other option. Requirement is to have rich UI which can be extended in future.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is for windows client application. Can be hosted in a web page but with many limitations. For rich UIs in web pages you can use ASP.NET MVC 3 or webforms. html5 and CSS 3 allow you to do a lot of things and without dependencies on proprietary technologies like WPF or SilverLight or Flash the web Ui will work / should be made to work on all browsers and platforms like the android I am using here now